# Replace all values in a list without using enumerate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, enumerator

Say I wanted to find all the values '6' in a list and replace it with the value '600'. I can accomplish this using *enumerate()* but I believe this is not a good way to do what I want to do. The problem I am facing is that I need to know the index in order to replace the value with a new one, hence the DATA[idx] .

```
DATA = [ 2,4,6,8,6,1,2,3,4,6]
      for idx, val in enumerate(DATA):
        if val == 6:
            DATA[idx]=600
```

But is there an alternate and/or more efficient way to do this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you explain what efficiency you mean.

Comment: Why do you think enumerate is not a good tool?  Sometimes you do need both value and index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
DATA = [2,4,6,8,6,1,2,3,4,6]
DATA = [600 if x == 6 else x for x in DATA]
print(DATA)
>> [2, 4, 600, 8, 600, 1, 2, 3, 4, 600]
```

EDIT: As requested -- BTW I'm not quite sure if this is exactly how Python implements it in the background, but here's a dumbed down version of the comprehension:

```
>>>> DATA = [600 if x == 6 else x for x in DATA]
DATA2 = []
for x in DATA:
    if x == 6:
        DATA2.append(600)
    else:
        DATA2.append(x)
DATA = DATA2
del(DATA2)
```

Comment: Hey AK47, can you please rewrite [600 if x == 6 else x for x in DATA] in the long way? I am not familiar with the shortcut version of these statements.

Comment: For every value in the list DATA, if x == 6, then use the value 600 instead or else just use the original value for x

Comment: @Mike: The syntax you are referring to is called list comprehension in Python. Here's a reference link for you: https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Comment: This creates a new list, unlike the OP's code. If you had multiple variables pointing to the original list, doing this will cause problems. Reassigning the list to the original name won't fix the problem; it'll still be a different list.

Comment: @AK47 - When you create a new list, you haven't replaced any of the values in the original list. I suggest you do some reading on how mutable objects work. Your and Steve's answers, as they stand, have a different result than the OP's code and are thus harmful to anyone who believes them to be drop-in replacements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "more efficient".  All you can do is walk the array and consider each value. Your code does this adequately.  I don't see a problem with it.

I can think of a number of other ways to do this.  A list comprehension is very compact:

```
   DATA = [600 if i == 6 else i for i in DATA]
```

This does create a new array though, so it's arguably a wee bit less efficient.  I can't think of a more compact way to walk a list and change entries in it in place.

Comment: OOPS. Someone beat me to the answer. We agree, so this is definitely your answer :)

Comment: This creates a new list, unlike the OP's code. If you had multiple variables pointing to the original list, doing this will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` with `len`:

```
for i in range(len(DATA)):
    if DATA[i] == 6:
        DATA[i] = 600
```

or slice assignment:

```
DATA[:] = [600 if item == 6 else item for item in DATA]
```

`enumerate` is probably best.

Comment: What good does the slice on the LHS do?  I'm guessing that you think this is more efficient because it's modifying the original list rather than replacing it.  But it's really no different, because the RHS creates a new list regardless.  It's just a matter of how the new list becomes DATA, and I'd be worried that your way of operating on the original list could be less efficient.  That depends on the compiler.

Comment: @Steve - The slice assignment puts all the recalculated elements into the original list, as the OP's code does but your answer does not. If a piece of code produces several references to this list and expects them to remain such, creating and assigning a new list could cause bugs.

Comment: Cool.  Didn't think of that.  I'll remember this for use in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your task is better to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)'s [boolean mask](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781784393670/3/ch03lvl1sec23/a-boolean-mask) for a very fast and convenient in-place substitution with an intuitive command

```
                              data[data == 6] = 600
```

---

The full code:

```
import numpy as np            # pip install numpy

DATA = [ 2,4,6,8,6,1,2,3,4,6]

data = np.array(DATA)         # converting to a NumPy array
data[data == 6] = 600         # data == 6 is a boolean mask; it is written in [] as an index
```

The output of `print(data)`:

> ```
>  [  2   4 600   8 600   1   2   3   4 600]
> ```

---

*Note 1:*

If you need to convert the resulting NumPy array back to a Python list, use `data = list(data)`:

> ```
> [2, 4, 600, 8, 600, 1, 2, 3, 4, 600]
> ```

---

*Note 2:*

It's confusing to use the name `DATA` (all caps) for something which you will later change -
see [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) and the part [Constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) in it.